# Do JRuby/Jython have purely-interpreted mode?

Tags: java, security, jvm, jruby, jython

I'm running code within a sandbox that disallows prettymuch everything (reflection/classloading/etc.). I can still run Rhino Javascript, since it (to a large part) doesn't do any of these things. However, everything I could find about JRuby/Jython point towards their JIT compiter or AOT compiler.

Do these projects have a dumb "i'll interpret the AST as i go along" mode? I'd be happy to take the order of magnitude performance hit (it's nothing intensive) to let it run within the restricted environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ohai ;)

Taking a look at the [JRuby GitHub wiki page](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/ConfiguringJRuby), we have

```
# Set compilation mode. JIT = at runtime; FORCE = before execution.
# Options: [JIT, FORCE, OFF, OFFIR], Default: JIT.
compile.mode=JIT
```

Answer (score 2):

Jython does not have a pure interpreted mode at this point. There is a beginning of one based on python bytecodes (that could be pure in memory and avoid all java bytecode issues) but it is not yet usable.